# tcp source port is not randomly

Tags: windows, linux-networking, tcp

When we trying to get a file from a web-server, sometimes access is not possible. After checking the communication with tcpdump, we saw that the Source-machine is randomly choosing a source-port for communication. This should be fine, but the “randomly choosing” is not that random as supposed. So source ports are very often reused after a short time (sometimes only 2 seconds). On destination System the socket is in TIME_WAIT status and so communication is dropped by the destination. The question is, why is the server choosing the source port not randomly enough (like 3388, 3345,2345,3388).

We are able to recreate the exactly same behavior when using wget with the following parameters:

```
wget -t 1 "xxx/test.html" -O /dev/null -o /dev/null -d --bind-address=yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

Then the system is choosing the port randomly, but not that random and if port is reused too shortly, then no communication is possible (resending SYN-Packets)

A liitle modification of the wget statement:

```
wget -t 1 "xxx/test.html" -O /dev/null -o /dev/null -d
```

and everything is working fine and ports are chosen one by one. Communication never hangs.

So our source system is working exactly like the first wget statement, but we need it to get working like the second one or choosing the ports more randomly. How to change the behavior of choosing-source-ports for TCP-Communications?

Comment: Has the local port range been reduced? Check with `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range`. Increase this if required.

Comment: the port range is not reduced and many ports are free

Comment: Can you check on the server you are trying to access whether `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle` is enabled (set to 1).

Comment: We try to access the windows server. But I think it's disabled by default?

Comment: Ah, it's a Windows server. I'm not sure if there is a tw_recycle option there. Just to confirm, sockets can generally reuse the same source port without issue because the ISN is expected to be increasing on each new SYN. A socket in TIME-WAIT should accept a new connection on the same socket, providing the Initial Sequence Number of the SYN is greater than the last sequence number seen on the socket. Does your source machine have a crazy connection rate which is wrapping the ISN too quickly?

Comment: no, there is no crazy connection rate, just a few connections within one minute. there is no reason why to reuse the source port as quick as it does. Once TCP connection is terminated with FIN,ACK; the requesting system maybe reuses the port within a few seconds and the new SYN has SEQ=0. so it is smaller then the old SEQ-Number and will not be accepted by the destination, because it is in TIME-WAIT.
Just for clairification: source-system (with wget) is SLES; Destination System (providing the files) is Windows.

Comment: The new SEQ will very likely not be 0. ISN numbers are chosen according to an [internal clock](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionEstablishmentSequenceNumberSynchroniz.htm). To quote "Any time a new connection is set up, the ISN was taken from the current value of this timer. Since it takes over 4 hours to count from 0 to 4,294,967,295 at 4 microseconds per increment, this virtually assured that each connection will not conflict with any previous ones."

Comment: hmm, ok, you are right, sorry. my wireshark showed relative sequence numbers, not absolute ones. I've changed the behaviour and now see teh right sequence numbers. Of course, the SEQ of the new connection is bigger, then the old one, also when it is not working properly. One example:

`SEQ in FIN, ACK: 2549807361`
`SEQ in new SYN:  2824252289`

Also: of course sometimes ports can be reused, but if they are reused three or four times within a short timespan, the destination will drop the SYN for this port in my case.

Comment: Hmm, let me have a think. Any chance you can upload a tcpdump/Wireshark capture of this issue on both sender and receiver (showing connection success followed by failure)?

Comment: Because an http connection is not encrypted, I can not provide the tcpdump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this locally and cannot replicate the behavior. Even when I set my linux machine to use only two local ports I am able to initiate multiple (20+) connections to the same domain (internal or external) without issue. I also ensure that the remote server is in TIME-WAIT state by setting the no-http-keep-alive header (and confirmed via netstat).

I discovered that when using the `--bind-address` flag for WGET, it uses Bind() to create the socket where the source IP is whatever is specified on the command line and the source port is chosen from `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range`. Whenever a new source port needs to be selected this will be the previous port + 2. After reaching the end of the source port range, it will wrap back around to the start and begin counting up in two's again.

When you omit the `--bind-address` flag, Connect() is used to establish the socket where the source IP is taken from the default interface and the source port is a random port in the `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range` range. New source ports will also be selected randomly from this range.

In either case, when a socket is reused, the Initial Sequence Number has been increased by the internal TCP clock, allowing servers to accept the new incarnation of the connection. This agrees with my testing of 20 connection requests using the same source port and increasing ISN values - all are accepted by the server in TIME-WAIT state.

If we exclude any weirdness being introduced by tcp_tw_recycle as I do not believe that option is present on a Windows server, the only other thing I can think of is a combination of:

- a small ephemeral port range configured on your Linux server which results in regular re-use of local ports when using `--bind-interface`.
- A firewall or some other network device between the client and server which is performing TCP Sequence Number randomisation. As a result, it cannot be relied upon that the Initial Sequence Numbers hitting the server will be greater than the previous connection and could result in dropped connections.

Comment: thank you to make it complete [click here for cisco link](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa82/configuration/guide/config/conns_connlimits.html#wp1080757)